# What are your top SAS PROCs for beginners?

Tags: sas, statistics

What procs are easy to learn and essential for SAS programming? I have learned several like proc print, sort, freq, format, univariate, anova, glm, import, transpose. What ones should I learn next?

Comment: Data step logic, SQL, and SAS Macro language can get you very far. Depending on your statistics focus, you can go down many routes: SAS/ETS procs are great for time series and forecasting (proc timeseries and proc expand are excellent tools for prepping time series data for forecasting), Viya VDMML has deep learning, proc MCMC does Bayesian analysis, proc optmodel solves optimization problems, proc IML is for matrix manipulation...there are so many choices!

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! I'll look into this

Comment: These are the top procs based upon a very large SAS program sample I have from a lot of sources:

SORT

SQL

TRANSPOSE

DATASETS

EXPORT

TABULATE

FORMAT

SUMMARY/MEANS

FREQ

IMPORT

APPEND

CONTENTS

GCHART

REPORT

PRINTTO

PRINT

MIXED

COPY

HTTP

Comment: You have a list so let me make some suggestions on what to use and what to avoid. Anything having to do with SAS doing the UI I would avoid (TABULATE, REPORT, GCHART, PRINT). Why? UI is best handled outside of the data side. YMMV. 

SQL is the biggie for new users but learn DATA step and SORT as well. The difference is very important vs SQL. IMPORT/EXPORT are key but so is HTTP. 

Really, really get to know PROC HTTP and why you need to use it. SUMMARY is my fav as is TRANSPOSE. HTTP shows you how to work with others.

Macro is a plague. Learn how to code without it as much as possible

Comment: MEANS, SGPLOT, SGPANEL, DS2. What SAS client do you use ? Display manager, enterprise guide, SAS Studio, other ?

Comment: Data step. Data step is the most complicated one and one that allows you to do almost anything if you want. Get the certification guide and get certified while you're at it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow (and SAS).  The procedures that AlanC mention are all important.

Probably your best bet is to pick up a copy of [The little SAS book](https://www.sas.com/store/books/categories/getting-started/the-little-sas-book-a-primer-sixth-edition/prodBK_73044_en.html) and learn the data processing as well as the analysis procedures.  I have used many versions of it for years and students like it.  SAS changes at a glacial pace.  So, if money is tight, pick up an older edition.

You have already hit many of the main procedures.  Focus on data processing with data step and PROC SQL.  SQL is its own language and is *extremely* useful with or without SAS.  Also do not neglect ODS.  SAS can make very beautiful output and the aesthetics matter when you are showing your portfolio.

If you want to be a professional SAS programmer you will need to learn macro, to automate tasks, and also the intermediate to advanced magic that Ron Cody writes about.  Get comfortable with the language then work on converting your code into macro.  Along the way be sure to check Cody's [data cleaning book](https://www.sas.com/store/books/categories/usage-and-reference/cody-s-data-cleaning-techniques-using-sas-third-edition/prodBK_70074_en.html)